# Распространить содержание ячейки на пустые ячейки под ней в LibreOffice

Tags: open-office

У меня есть табличка в LibreOffice Calc.
Если значение ячейки совпадает со значением ячейки над ней, то эта ячейка остается пустой.
Теперь мне вдруг понадобилось эту табличку сортировать. Сортировка не понимает, что подразумевается под пустой ячейкой и получается ерунда.

Есть какой-то способ распространить содержание ячейки на пустые ячейки под ней (до следующей непустой ячейки)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это делает расширение [Tools For Calc Edit](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/tools-for-calc-edit).

Comment: А вы, случайно, не автор или разработчик этого расширения?

Comment: @Nick Volynkin, Случайно нет :) Я потратила несколько дней на поиск решения, нашла макрос, но не смогла заставить его работать, и уже думала написать решение самой. Я была счастлива, когда нашла это расширение. Поэтому я решила поделиться с народом, может еще кому пригодится.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin, А что, здесь есть ограничения или особый формат для вопросов о своих программах?

Comment: да, в таком случае было бы необходимо явно указать, что вы автор и предлагаете именно свой продукт. )